# Как в bash скрипте проверить название файла на наличие в нем цифр

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Как написать скрипт bash который ищет файлы в названии которых есть более трех цифр? Я чет пытался сделать через маску, но я новичок в линуксе. Помогите пж)

Comment: Более трех цифр подряд или вообще? ``bo12ook34.txt`` - более трех цифр? А ``boo12k3.tx4``?

Comment: Да, более трех цифр в целом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## find

Искать файлы разумно через `find` с простой маской:

```
find /lib/ -name "*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*"
```

Кавычки чтоб не сработал glob встроенный в bash или zsh. (Иногда получаются неожиданные эффекты)

## glob

Через `glob` сразу делайте с файлами что хотели:

```
 ls -la *[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*
```

Или там

```
tar czf ../backup.tar.gz *[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*
```

Во всех примерах попадутся ещё и каталоги с такой маской.

Квадратные скобки работают без опций. Дополнения некоторые надо включать в баше.

### globstar

Эта опция даёт вам сверхспособности по подстановке! Если ввести:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ ls **
```

тогда оболочка покажет рекурсивно все каталоги и подкаталоги.

### extglob

Эта опция активирует функции, которые чаще ассоциируются с регулярными выражениями. Иногда это очень полезно:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ touch afile bfile cfile
$ ls
afile bfile cfile
$ ls ?(a*|b*)
afile bfile
$ ls !(a*|b*)
cfile
```

Здесь шаблоны помещаются в круглые скобки и разделяются вертикальной чертой. Вот доступные операторы:

```
? = соответствует нулю или одному вхождению заданных шаблонов
! = показать всё, что не соответствует заданным шаблонам
* = ноль или более вхождений
+ = одно или более вхождений
@ = ровно одно вхождение
```

Comment: спасибо за пример. +1

Comment: из https://habr.com/ru/post/452522/ дополнил описание

Answer (score -1):

Один из вариантов:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find ${1:-.} -type f |
while read PATH_FILE
do
    COUNT_OF_DIGITS=`basename $PATH_FILE | sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g'`
    [ ${#COUNT_OF_DIGITS} -lt 4 ] || echo $PATH_FILE
done
```

Вызов: script.sh [DIR]

где DIR - необязательный параметр - путь к директории, в которой искать файлы. Если параметр не указан то поиск в текущей.

Comment: у меня выдает что-то типа " ./script: строка 6: [: пропущен `]' "

Comment: Зачем костылить когда есть glob

Comment: @ДенисГудойть Скрипт рабочий, я его проверял перед тем как сюда выложить и перепроверил снова. Если вы вточности скопировали текст, который я привел, то приведеной Вами ошибки в 6 строке быть не может.

Comment: @eri, интересно увидеть решение с Glob. Покажете?

Comment: @Jigius Отличается лишь первой строчкой у меня -> #!/bin/bash.